# Microsoft SQL 2005 Simple Trigger How to: Coded a trigger that doesn't update anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Confused about triggers:  I have two types of records, 'L' library and 'N' normal.  When an 'N' is updated or inserted, I need to update the corresponding 'L'.  Updates to 'L' records shouldn't update themselves.  **This code doesn't let an update succeed.  Why?**

```
ALTER trigger updateProductLibrary
on Product
after update as
BEGIN
    -- either deleted (old) or inserted (new)
    declare @counter int, @insertedType char(1)
    set @insertedType = 'Z'

    select @insertedType = i.type
    from inserted i

    if( @insertedType = 'N')
    begin
        select @counter = count(*)
        from product p join inserted i on
        p.sku = i.sku and
        p.type = 'L' -- for library

        if( @counter > 0) -- update
        BEGIN
            update p set name = i.name
            from product p join inserted i on
                 p.sku = i.sku and
                 p.type = 'L'
        END
        ELSE -- insert
        BEGIN
            insert into product (sku, name, type)
            select  i.sku, i.name, 'L'
            from inserted i
        END
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic error is that you appear to expect this trigger to be called once for each row. This is **NOT** the case - it will be called once for each batch.

So this statement here isn't going to work, many times:

```
select @insertedType = i.type
from inserted i
```

What would that select, if you have 10 entries in your `inserted` pseudo-table ??

You need to rewrite your trigger to take into account that the `inserted` table can contain **multiple rows** !

Comment: Wow.  I completely missed that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger needs to support multiple rows per update.

```
ALTER TRIGGER updateProductLibrary ON dbo.Product AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE p
    SET name = i.name
    FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN dbo.Product p
            ON p.sku = i.sku
            AND p.type = 'L'
    WHERE i.type = 'N'

    INSERT INTO product (sku, name, type)
    SELECT i.sku, i.name, 'L'
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.type = 'N'
        AND i.sku NOT IN
            (SELECT p.sku
            FROM dbo.Product p
            WHERE p.type = 'L')
END
```